# How to stop Laravel 4 from returning passwords?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I'm developing an application using laravel 4. I'm performing the following join on two tables:

```
$listings = DB::table('user')
    ->join('listings', 'listings.agent_id', '=', 'user.id')
    ->where('user.user_level', '=', 3)
    ->get();

var_dump($listings);
```

Not this works as expected, but in the var_dump it returns the hashed password which I don't want it to do.

```
public 'password' => string '$2y$10$o58S16Tw2yc2uvcIs.cy3.lbmyFgUZjTl7nMdLzU2AVXeXVCY5xqK' (length=60)
```

I have in my User Model:

```
protected $hidden = array('password');
```

But, I think this only hides it from a Json response. So, in this situation I have two questions:

1. Is it bad to have the password out like this? It is coming back hashed, but I still don't like the fact that it's out there. Obviously, I won't be using the var_dump like this in the live application, but the fact that the information is there makes me nervous.
2. If it is bad, how can I prevent it? I want all the rest of the info in the tables. So, I could re-write my query to return everything but the password, but is there a simpler way to do this? Perhaps I'm missing something that excludes rows in my query, as opposed to writing every row I want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all I would recommend you to create a model for each database table.

Next if you are using DB::table('user') you are not making use of the User model where the $hidden is specified. This way the password will not be hidden.

When you're doing this (for example):

```
$user = User::find(1); // Selects user with id of 1
return Response::json($user); // Gives JSON response
```

All the user data will be shown as JSON, without the fields specified in:

```
protected $hidden = ['password'];
```

I hope this helps you out ;)